# how to calculate gross salary when net salary and percentage of deduction is known

Tags: arithmetic

When net salary is 10350 and 13.75% pf deducted  how gross amount is calculated..

For eg: If gross salary is 12000,  pf is 13.75% then

net salary= 12000* 13.75% 
          = 10350
But how to calculate reverse way wen we know net salary as 10350 and pf deduction as 13.75%
using simple formula

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let us call $N$ the net salary, $G$ the gross salary and $x$ the percentage corresponding to the pf deduction. So, you have $$N=G\times (1-\frac{x}{100})$$ This gives you the relation between the three quantities. From this, you can extract $G$ and get $$G=\frac{100 N}{100-x}$$